# Making Gephi run on a hosted Microsoft server

Tags: opengl, cloud, gephi

Has anyone had success with running Gephi on a Microsoft server? I get the issue "OpenGl 1.1.0" too low version. I need OpenGl 1.5 according to Gephi. As I don't have a support plan, getting in touch with MS is a pain.

The alternative is to purchase a pc, but I would prefer a shared setup as we are multiple analysts who aim to run multiple analyses ad hoc and so benefits from a scalable server setup. Any other alternative suggestions are well received.

Comment: It shows the same message to me but still runs ok. Did you have any more specific issues?

Comment: Yes, Gephi freezes up after a few operations. I have to close the application by using the Windows Job list (ctrl + alt + del).

Comment: Well Gephi would do that even with the right OpenGL I 'm afraid. What *operations* are you referring to?

Comment: I apologise for the delay. Operations might have been a misleading word - I was referring to ordinary features, such as setting degree and doing statistics. However, I just testet Gephi on newer machine and everything works perfectly (and no openGl error message!). So I bought a new PC :). Thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I found was to purchase a PC with a newer graphics card (= newer version of OpenGl).